On the convergence of $\sum_{n\geq0}a_n\cos(nx)$

Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that
$\sum_{n\geq0}a_n$ converges absolutely. Can we say that
$\sum_{n\geq0}a_n\cos(nx)$ converges to a continuous function?

I know that $\sum_{n\geq0}a_n\cos(nx)$ must converge pointwise, since it converges absolutely by the inequality $$\sum_{n\geq0}\vert a_n\cos(nx)\vert\leq \sum_{n\geq0}\vert a_n\vert.$$
But the continuity of the function seems to me a much stronger condition, I believe it is false, but I cannot think of a counterexample.

Can you see that $\sum_{n\geq0}a_n\cos(nx)$ converges uniformly in $x$?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test

Very clear, thank you :)
